# JQuery Get and Post not working in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I created an action in mvc, and I tried to call the action using jquery.get. The resulting response was `not found(404)`. Following is the action method and `jquery` code.

Error:

> GET http://localhost:52050/Products/PriceWithTax?pid=1 404 (Not Found)

Latest `Jquery 3.4.1` is included in `Bundle.config`.

Action Method in MVC

```
 public decimal PriceWithTax(int pid)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var product = dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == pid);
            return (decimal)((product.Price * 0.18m) + product.Price);
        }
```

Jquery in .cshtml page

````
@section Scripts{
    <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#Id").blur(function () {
                    var productId = $(this).val();
                    var tax = jQuery("#txtTax");
                    jQuery.get('@Url.Action("PriceWithTax","Products")', { pid: productId }, function (data) {
                        tax.val(data);
                      });
                    //jQuery.get('/Products/PriceWithTax', { pid: productId }, function (data) {
                    //    tax.val(data);
                    //});
                });
            });
    </script>
}```
I tried $ instead on jQuery and get instead of post
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your action method to return `JsonResult` rather than `decimal` as following:

```
public JsonResult PriceWithTax(int pid)
{
   ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
   var product = dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == pid);
   var value = (decimal)((product.Price * 0.18m) + product.Price);
   return Json(value,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

for more documentation about action result types check this [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/action-method-in-mvc)

Comment: note the `[HttpGet]` is optional as the action will default to a GET

Comment: yes it is optional you can ignore it by default it will be get.

Comment: I tried but still showing the same error, it is not calling the method at all. I set a breakpoint and checked

Comment: what is your controller name?what is the base type of it?

Comment: public class ProductsController : Controller

Comment: @ArunKumar it seems fine, can you try updated answer

Comment: Still not working I tried using jquery. Ajax too but no use. I even disabled the anti virus.

Comment: @Arun is it return the same exception